# How to sample from an hypergeometric distribution mathematically?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, cryptography

There are lots of implementations of functions that sample from hypergeometric distributions and they use these 2 constants:

```
    D1 = 1.7155277699214135
    D2 = 0.8989161620588988
```

an example is here:

http://project-thrill.org/docs/master/classthrill_1_1common_1_1hypergeometric__distribution.html

All of these examples use the function names `hypergeometric_hyp` and `hypergeometric_hrua`:

```
◆ rk_hypergeometric_hyp()
◆ rk_hypergeometric_hrua()
```

what are them, where I can read about the theory behind this implementation? What's the difference between `hyp` and `hrua`?

Comment: Ctrl+F to the first appearance of "discrete" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: @J.G. "Note that for a discrete distribution, computing the CDF is not in general too difficult: we simply add up the individual probabilities for the various points of the distribution". This would be the costly way of doing it. I don't think it's done like this on the `hyp` and `hrua` functions

Comment: The source code is lines 153-216 [here](http://project-thrill.org/docs/master/hypergeometric__distribution_8hpp_source.html). `rk_hypergeometric_hyp` works as I suggested; `rk_hypergeometric_hrua` uses [a more complicated approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).

Comment: @J.G. how do you know about that complicated approach? I couldn't find it related to the code by reading the wikipedia about rejection sampling. Do you know some literature about the exact method used in the code which uses the log gamma function?

Comment: Apparently, the HRUA algorithm is described in [Stadlover 1989](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256371290_Sampling_from_Poisson_binomial_and_hypergeometric_distributions_ratio_of_uniforms_as_a_simple_and_fast_alternative) Sec. 5.2 d, but I can't find any source on Frohne's 1989 improvement to HRUA, viz. line 219.